# Compress data being sent over socat

Tags: udp, socat

I'm using the [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) command as follows:

```
socat -T10 UDP4-LISTEN:port,reuseaddr,fork TCP:host:port
```

on the client side and the command

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:port,reuseaddr,fork UDP:host:port
```

on the remote end to send udp packets bidirectionally between the source and the destination.
Is it possible to compress the data being sent to and fro?

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into this issue myself. I'm trying to set up 2 points, one in CentOS and another on Windows Server that use compression. I've looked into socat and the only option seems to be using SSL compression over that connection. I'm also investigating PPP but it seems to have fallen out of use.

This here helped: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/22262q/tunnel_with_socat_over_compressed_connection/

Good luck there mate.

Comment: Please note that TLS1.3 will no longer support compression and that in some Linux distributions libssl is now compiled without compression. So using SSL/TLS to solve this problem is deprecated.